# Tagging bug - 'testacular'

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tag-synonyms

Just posted about 'testacular' on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15833736/testacular-install-failes-no-vcbuild-exe), every time I enter the tag 'testacular' and save, it gets converted to 'karma-runner'.

Comment: Look here for an explanation of why the synonym was made: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174508/add-testacular-as-synonym-for-karma-runner

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because `testacular` is a synonym of tag [karma-runner](/questions/tagged/karma-runner)